# My Terraria NPC will not settle down in a house

Tags: terraria

I have made an arena for the moon lord boss battle and made a small house for the nurse to move into. It says the message that the NPC moved in and the nurse banner is there, but no matter what I do, she won't move into the house and will just walk around outside.

Comment: Have you tried exiting your world and loading back into it? Sometimes a little session reset like that is enough to move NPCs.

Comment: If her banner is in the house, then at night or when it rains she should teleport there if offscreen. If after that and restarting your game it still doesn't work, why don't you edit your question with a picture of the house?

Answer (score 3):

Wait until night and make sure the nurse and her house are out of view. After you've done that, she should teleport into her room. If, after that, you find her outside of her house, she has found a way out and you can simply repeat and she will be back.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a house where you want the nurse to be. To force her to get in, you can simply get a couple of blocks, maybe 200 and whenever the nurse moves forward, you put blocks behind her, so she can't go back and be forced in the house. You may need to put her banner in the house first, tho.